# Delta table configuration in open source and databricks version are different

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I'm trying to setup the isolation level to Serializable on open source delta using azure synapse notebook.

Command :

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table SET TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.isolationLevel' = 'Serializable')
```

It seems like delta is not able to identify the configuration

```
Error: Unknown configuration was specified: delta.isolationLevel org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaErrors$.unknownConfigurationKeyException(DeltaErrors.scala:398) org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaConfigsBase.$anonfun$validateConfigurations$3(DeltaConfig.scala:147) scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189) org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaConfigsBase.$anonfun$validateConfigurations$1(DeltaConfig.scala:147) scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
```

The same command works in databricks delta. Is this expected ? Why is this inconsistency between databricks delta and open delta ?

Answer (score 0):

The command which you are trying is using t-sql type of syntax which is compatible to work with Databricks. On synapse spark pool, can you try below command and see if it works for you.

spark.sql("ALTER TABLE schema.table SET TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.isolationLevel' = 'Serializable')")

Comment: https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/1129
This is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, isolation level not exposed in open source delta version

https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/1265